# 3 Scenarios for most relevant keywords in website. Which one is best?

Tags: seo, google, web-development, keywords, optimization

A webpage about **Tomato Soup** has either of three following filenames:

> ***Scenario 1***
>   website.org/en/tomato-soup

or

> ***Scenario 2***
>   website.org/en/tomato-soup-healthy-soups-recipes

or

> ***Scenario 3***
>   website.org/en/tomato-why-sandra-is-so-wild-about-her-healthy-tomato-soup-recipes

Q1. Which one of the abobe would You go for?
Q2. Which one of these would be ranked as most relevant by google?
Q3. Would either of these be penalized for keyword stuffing?

Comment: Thought about `website.org/en/recipes/soups/tomato` ?

Comment: @Tom, how would that differenciate in comparison to `website.org/en/recipes-soups-tomato` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Depends on the what the content is. That's how you determine what the title should be. , #3 is best assuming it is about Sandra's healthy tomato soup recipes, and not the recipes themselves. Those recipes should have titles like:

```
website.org/en/recipes/healthy-chicken-broth
website.org/en/recipes/tomato-soup
website.org/en/nutrition/tomato-soup
```

2) Relevance depends on what the search term is. My second example above would be the most relevant for "tomato soup recipes". The second and third would be both relevant for "tomato soup".

3) No.

Comment: +1 for very clear and satisfying answer! I think I'm slowly understanding this issue...

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends. If your web site is providing everything about Tomato Soup, or tomato Soup is a very competitive keywords, then I will use the first one,

```
website.org/en/tomato-soup
```

Why? Because your web site gets more choice to show up when some search tomato Soup. If you use the second one or third one, your keyword tomato soup will be deluted by health or other words, in that case it is very hard to compete with some using the first url.

That being said, if you want to attract visitors who are health concourse, and incline to use long tail keyword like "how can I keep healthy by having tomato soup"or "it is good for my health to have tomato soup," then you get a good shot by sticking to the last one.

So do your home work. And GOOD LUCK